# Hybrid Android app not connecting to MobileFirst server

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

In my QA environment, the hybrid Android app does not connect to the MFP server.
On my local machine, using the MFP CLI tooling, the app connects without issue.
In my QA environment, the hybrid iPhone app connects to the MFP server.

The callback on the failed `WL.Client.connect()` gets this error object:

```
{
  "status": 403
}
```

Here is the stack trace from the error handler:

```
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971): file:///android_asset/www/default/assets/js/dependencies.js: Line 23 : trace: Error
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at Object.connectionFailure [as onFailure] (file:///android_asset/www/default/assets/js/dependencies.js:23:190)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at onFailureResetSettings (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:8251:12)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at onInitFailure (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:8245:4)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at Object.onFailure (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:951:20)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onFailure (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3650:26)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at klass.window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlFailure (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3599:12)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at Object.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3437:27)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at Object.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1202:33)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at fire (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1047:30)
08-25 14:31:56.016: D/CordovaLog(27971):     at Object.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1158:7)
```

I don't see anything in the server logs about a rejected connection request.

I'm calling `WL.Client.connect()` from the success handler of my `WL.Client.init()` call, which is itself called on the window load event.

(**NOTE**: based on comments below I've changed to calling `connect()` from `wlCommonInit()` but there's no change ... the stack trace above is from that scenario)

Here is the code doing the connect:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myng-worklight', [])
    .run(WorklightRun)

  WorklightRun.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$q'];

  /**
  * Load worklight
  */
  function WorklightRun($rootScope, $q) {

    // Worklight statuss
    var worklightDeferred = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.worklightPromise = worklightDeferred.promise;
    $rootScope.worklightLoaded = false;
    $rootScope.worklightConnected = false;

    var worklightLoadEvent = null;
    worklightLoadEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');

    // Worklight connect options
    var wlConnectOptions = {
      timeout: 30000,

      onFailure: connectionFailure,

      onSuccess: function () {
        console.log('MFP: Connected');
        $rootScope.worklightConnected = true;
        worklightDeferred.resolve();
      }
    };

    // Worklight init options
    var wlInitOptions = {
      timeout: 10000,

      onConnectionFailure: connectionFailure,

      onFailure: connectionFailure,

      onSuccess: function () {
        console.log('MFP: Loaded');
        $rootScope.worklightLoaded = true;
        if (window.addEventListener) {
          window.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, wlConnectedHandler, true);
          window.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, wlDisconnectedHandler, true);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
          window.attachEvent(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, wlConnectedHandler);
          window.attachEvent(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, wlDisconnectedHandler);
        }
        console.log('MFP: About to connect with: ' + JSON.stringify(wlConnectOptions, null, 2));
        WL.Client.connect(wlConnectOptions);
      }
    };
    // we should connect on the cb from init -- output!

    // Listen for load / onload and start worklight init
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('load', loadHandler, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onload', loadHandler);
    }


    function connectionFailure(err) {
      console.log('MFP: No Connection - ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      worklightDeferred.reject(err);
    }

    function loadHandler() {
      try {
        console.log('MFP: Load event detected, about to init with: ' + JSON.stringify(wlInitOptions, null, 2));
        WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('MFP: "WL" not defined - ' + err);
        connectionFailure();
        worklightLoadEvent.initCustomEvent('worklightLoadFailure', true, false, {});
        window.dispatchEvent(worklightLoadEvent);
      }
    }

    function wlConnectedHandler() {
      $rootScope.worklightConnected = true;
      WL.App.hideSplashScreen();
    }

    function wlDisconnectedHandler() {
      $rootScope.worklightFailureAcknowledged = true;
      $rootScope.worklightConnected = false;
      WL.App.hideSplashScreen();
    }
  }
})();
```

Possibly this is related to the Android app authenticity settings? (e.g. publicSigningKey in `application-descriptor.xml` or the `customTests` in `authenticationConfig.xml`)

Here is the relevant bit from `application-descriptor.xml`:

```
<android securityTest="customTests" version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="false"/>
    <pushSender key="XYZ" senderId="123"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        <publicSigningKey>MIIBI...</publicSigningKey>
        <packageName>com.MyPackage</packageName>
    </security>
</android>
```

And from `authenticationConfig.xml`:

```
<customSecurityTest name="customTests">
  <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2" />
</customSecurityTest>
```

Comment: Calling connect from the success handler of init?! Who told you to do it that way? Please add your implementation.

Comment: @IdanAdar - it looked like we were having race conditions between the `init()` completing and the call to `connect()`. How should we do a manual call to `connect()` ?

Comment: This is not the implementation code I asked for. Add the code where you do the connect.

Comment: I'll add that too ... given that I'm seeing a `403` now, I thought it might have to do with the app authenticity config. Still, I'll add the other code.

Comment: MFP code should run once wlCommonInit is called, which is where the WL.Client.connect method should be, and not be used directly via WL.Client.init. Please, next time do mention all of details at once, like the fact you're using authenticity and implement your app the way you did, we can't read your mind and know this...

Comment: thanks @IdanAdar - `wlCommonInit()` ... what is the mechanism for that (I can't find a description of in by searching the info center)? Is the function found by introspection and called when ready? Do we not need to call `WL.Client.init()` and just implement the call to `WL.Client.connect()` from `wlCommonInit()`?

Comment: It is located in main.js; it is automatically called when the Worklight framework is ready.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is wrong.

You should not call `WL.Client.connect` in this manner.
Worklight API should be called inside the `wlCommonInit()` function, located in the common\main.js file, and not from the common\initOptions.js file.

Look at the various sample applications provided at the [Developer Center](http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/all-tutorials). None of them are implemented in this manner... (it doesn't matter the samples are for 7.1 and you're using 6.2, as the concept is the same).

All of the onSuccess should not be done that way;

Comment: I have changed the code to implement `wlCommonInit()`. The results are the same, and the calls happen in the same order as they did with the original implementation.

(btw, we're using 7.0)

Comment: I've updated the question with the error object and stack trace.

Comment: Create a new app and do just a connect in wlCommonInit, does it connect?

Comment: I am still getting the 403 on Android. (It works on iOS.) I think it must have to do with the app authenticity/customTests. But there's no output on the server about it rejecting a connection attempt (or maybe that's logged somewhere other than the places available from the MFP console?)

Comment: If authenticity had failed you would get a pop-up with generic text. Are you getting any pop-up? this would also be logged in messages.log.